# Mots simultanément féminins et masculins

Tags: genre, lexique

Le nom « mi-temps » est soit masculin soit féminin, suivant le contexte (et donc le sens) dans le quel on l'utilise :

> mi-temps */mi.tɑ̃/* féminin invariable
>
> 1. (Sport) Dans certains sports (notamment au football), moitié du temps du jeu, marquée par une pause.
> 2. ...

Et :

> mi-temps */mi.tɑ̃/* masculin invariable
>
> 1. Emploi pour un nombre d’heures restreint.
> 2. ...

Existe-t-il d'autres mots de la langue française possédant cette même particularité ?

Comment: La formulation du titre avec *simultanément* est étrange. Dans les exemples cités ici, il s'agit de mots différents homophones/homographes qui ne sont pas **simultanément** masculin et féminin avec le même sens contrairement à *clope* donné dans une des réponses. Plus généralement, des centaines de mots français sont *simultanément* masculins et féminins avec le même sens : *linguiste, philosophe, psychologue, etc.*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On peut ajouter mousse à la liste des mots déjà cités :

[- Le mousse : apprenti marin, matelot
 - La mousse : végétal, amas de bulles](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/mousse)

et aussi, après <s>un peu</s> beaucoup de recherche

- [Barde](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/barde)
- [Baume](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/baume)
- [Crêpe](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/cr%C3%AApe)
- [Faune](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/faune)
- [Faux](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/faux)
- [Foudre](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/foudre)
- [Garde](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/garde)
- [Gîte](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/g%C3%AEte)
- [Greffe](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/greffe)
- [Le boum](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/boum) / [La boum](http://atilf.atilf.fr/dendien/scripts/tlfiv5/visusel.exe?198;s=401142285;r=5;nat=;sol=1;)
- [Merci](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/moule)
- [Mode](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/mode)
- [Mort](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/more)
- [Moule](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/office)
- [Office](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/office)
- [Ombre](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/ombre)
- [Page](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/page)
- [Plastique](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/plastique)
- [Platine](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/platine)
- [Poêle](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/po%C3%AAle)
- [Pupille](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/pupille)
- [Solde](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/solde)
- [Somme](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/somme)
- [Vague](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/vague)
- [Vase](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/vase)
- [Voile](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/voile)

Comment: Le genre grammatical suit juste le genre biologique. Ce n'est pas pareil que « mi-temps » dont le genre dépend du sens.

Comment: Comment un adjectif peut avoir genre ?

Comment: @Fractaliste Les adjectifs s'accordent en genre. Je me suis mal exprimé, réponse mise à jour.

Comment: rajoutez aussi "apres-midi"

Comment: @Memes Non, *après-midi* ne change pas de sens suivant le genre qu'on lui donne.

Comment: ah mince, j'avais loupe le coup du changement de sens :)

Answer (score 13):

Le mot *mi-temps* n'a pas deux sens selon le contexte mais selon le genre. Ce n'est pas le contexte qui définit les deux sens mentionnés de ce mots mais bien le genre. Une *mi-temps* est forcément une moitié de temps de jeu. Un *mi-temps* est un emploi (qui n'est pas travaillé à 100%).

[Wikipedia donne des exemples](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genre_grammatical#Mots_ayant_les_deux_genres) de mots ayant deux sens selon le genre:

> - [œuvre](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/oeuvre)
> - [enseigne](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/enseigne)
> - [manœuvre](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/manoeuvre)
> - [mémoire](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/memoire)
> - [manche](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/manche)
> - [poste](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/poste)

D'autres mots dont le genre varie avec le sens:

- [hymne](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/hymne)
- [tour](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/tour)
- [livre](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/livre) ([réponse de mansuétus](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/9332/176))
- [mousse](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/mousse) ([réponse de jlliagre](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/9315/176))

Comment: suggestion: j'ajouterai ceci:
**Une moitié** de temps  -> une mi-temps
**Un emploi** à moitié de temps -> un emploi à mi-temps -> un mi-temps

Answer (score 9):

[La réponse de Laurent G.](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/9311/176) donne des mots dont le sens varie avec le genre.  Il y a quelques autres mots dont le genre dépend d'autre chose.

- Classiquement, [*amour*](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/amour), [*délice*](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/delice) et [*orgue*](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/orgue) sont masculins au singulier et féminins au pluriel (la vigueur de cet usage dépend de qui on écoute).
- L'accord des adjectifs avec [*gens*](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/gens) est particulier (masculin pour les adjectifs qui suivent, parfois féminin pour ceux qui précèdent -- il faut que je retrouve la règle pour la citer)

Comment: *Gens* gouverne le masculin, sauf quand il est immédiatement précédé d'un adjectif à forme féminine distincte : "Toutes ces bonnes gens" (Le petit Robert) - *Gent* est féminin quand c'est un nom, sinon comme adjectif c'est  *gent* et *gente* selon le genre.

Answer (score 4):

En argot, clope est a la fois masculin et féminin. Une clope est une cigarette, tandis qu'un clope est un mégot de cigarette.

Comment: Une clope vient de 'un clope'. Le genre et le sens a dévié, les vieux dictionnaires ne parlent que de clopes au masculin...

Answer (score 3):

Le mot à genre moyennement défini par l'usage le plus employé est certainement «*après-midi*». Les deux genres sont corrects, ce qui n'est pas le cas de «*mi-temps*» dont le genre définit clairement le sens.

Dans le même style que mi-temps :

- un «*livre*», qu'on lit le soir (ou qu'on utilise comme rehausseur pour ses enfants)
- une «*livre*», qu'on utilise pour payer (quand on n'a plus de bitcoin, évidemment)

Comment: 'une livre' est une [unité de masse](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Livre_(unit%C3%A9_de_masse)), 453,592 37 ou 500 grammes suivant les pays. La Livre utilisé pour payer est l'abréviation de 'la Livre Sterling' qui normalement prend une majuscule étant une monnaie.

Answer (score 2):

Les documents sur la typographie rappellent souvent que le mot *espace* est [féminin](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Espace_(typographie)) quand il s'agit du caractère (matériel ou informatique) qui sert à séparer les mots, et masculin dans tous les autres cas.

Answer (score 1):

*Le tour*, l*a tour*

> En faisant le tour de Paris, j'ai visité la tour Eiffel.

Answer (score 0):

Certains mots sont à la fois féminins et masculins pour le même sens et le même emploi. Ils sont peu nombreux mais l'exemple le plus simple et marquant est **après-midi**.
On dit aussi bien **une après-midi** que **un après-midi**
Selon le [Larousse](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/apr%C3%A8s-midi/4816),

> après-midi :
>   nom masculin ou féminin invariable

Comment: Oui, mais ça ne répond pas à la question posée puisque le sens ne change pas.

Answer (score -1):

Il y a des mots, notamment d'origine étrangère, dont le genre n'est pas clairement défini en français. C'est par exemple le cas de **goulash**.

Comment: Oui mais ce n'est pas pareil que « mi-temps » dont le genre dépend du sens.

Comment: @Gilles - Je n'ai jamais dit que c'était pareil. J'attire juste l'attention sur des mots qui sont masculins ou féminins sans nécessairement changer de sens. Mais peut-être la question ne porte pas sur ces mots-là.

Answer (score -2):

Il y a aussi **enzyme** qui jadis était exclusivement féminin et aujourd'hui est aussi masculin.

Comment: Mais le sens reste le même!