# Quelle raison fait qu'un mot puisse être masculin et féminin à la fois ?

Tags: genre, origine-ou-raison

J'ai trouvé quelques mots comme

1. icône
2. source

Qui peuvent être à la fois masculin ou féminin. Je me demande pour quelle raison ? Est-il logique de trouver des mots pareils?

Comment: est-ce que cela t'aides ? http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/9310/mots-simultan%C3%A9ment-f%C3%A9minins-et-masculins/9312#9312

Comment: *Icône* (origine grecque via le russe) est toujours féminin. C'est le mot *icone* (emprunt à l'anglais) qui est employé tantôt au masculin tantôt au féminin.

Comment: Il existe, le mot « icone » sans accent ? Je n’en trouve trace nulle-part.

Comment: Pour une liste de mots similaires : http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/9310

Comment: @Édouard: Je l'ai sous les yeux dans le *Dictionnaire historique de la langue française*, dans le *Petit Robert*, et voir [wikipedia](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ic%C3%B4ne_%28informatique%29) note 1.

Comment: @Laure icone au masculin ?! Je n'ai pas compris dans quel contexte. C'est pour la traduction de l'anglais *icon* en informatique ? Si oui je n'ai jamais entendu ça en travaillant dans le domaine depuis des années, ni par des débutants, ni par des spécialistes... ou bien je n'ai pas compris ta remarque ?

Comment: À mon avis, la question n’est pas un doublon : l’autre question demande *une liste* de tels mots ; celle-ci demande des explications sur leurs origines. Je ne suis pas convaincu que la question aie beaucoup de mérite telle quenelle est formulée à l’heure actuelle, cela dit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Icône](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/icone) est féminin.

D’après le TLF, [source](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/source) peut être masculin quand il est l’élision de « code source ». Dans ce cas, il est masculin parce que « code » l’est. Cela dit, j’ai personnellement tendance à employer « source » au féminin même dans ce cas.

Je pense qu’il est vain d’espérer trouver une explication générale ou une logique générale sous-jacente derrière ce type de mots. M’est avis qu’il ne s’agit que de cas particuliers.